# System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0 in test Class

Tags: apex, unit-test

My apex class is

```
tempinvoiceid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('tempinvoiceid');
 tempin = [select name,Invoice_contact__c,First_Name__c,State__c,Invoice_policy__c,Invoice_Check__c,Last_Name__c,country__c,Email__c from Invoice__c where id=:tempInvoiceid];
 paypolicy = [select id,Early_Days__c,early_Payment__c, invoice_policy__c from payment_policy__c where early_payment__c = true and invoice_policy__c = :tempin[0].Invoice_policy__c]; //getting error here
```

My test class is

```
    public static testmethod void testsitepage(){
    test.starttest();
     Invoice_Policy__c newpolicy = new Invoice_policy__c(name='testPolicy',net__c='3',policy_status__c='Active');
        insert newpolicy;
        system.debug('newpolicyy'+newpolicy);

        payment_policy__c newpay = new payment_policy__c(name='testEarlyPayment',early_payment__c = true,Early_Days__c='2',Invoice_Policy__c = newpolicy.id);
        insert newpay;

       Invoice__c newIn = new Invoice__c(First_Name__c = 'test',state__c='Hyderabad', Invoice_policy__c=newpolicy.id);
        insert newIn;

        apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().put('id',newpolicy.id);
        sitepage sp = new sitepage();
        etc.......
}
```

Invoice__c -------- Invoice_policy__c(lookup)
payment_policy__c --------- Invoice_policy__c(lookup)

Help!!!!

Comment: in the class the field on `payment_policy__c` is `invoice_policy__c ` but in the test it's `Invoice_Polici__c`. Typo or you really have 2 similar fields?

Comment: its a typo.Only 1 field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that you are trying to access an index in a list that doesn't exist.  In this case that index is 0. The list access that you do on the line that is causing the error is `tempin[0].Invoice_policy__c`.

Your Apex class begins by getting an Id parameter, however your test class never sets that parameter in any of the code that you posted:

Apex class:

`tempinvoiceid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('tempinvoiceid');`

Test class:

`apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().put('id',newpolicy.id);`

Short answer: You put into the Map with a key of **id**, but get from the Map with a key of **tempinvoiceid**.

Longer answer:
The `getParameters()` method returns a [Map](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm).  When you call `.put('id',newpolicy.id)` in your test class you are putting a Map entry with a key of **id** into the Map.  In your Apex class when you call `.get('tempinvoiceid')` you are attempting to get a Map value with a key of **tempinvoiceid**.  Since you never put a Map entry with a key of **tempinvoiceid** into the Map `null` is returned as per the [Map.get specification](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_map.htm).  On the next line your `where id=:tempInvoiceid` evaluates to `where id = null` which results in an empty (i.e., size 0) List being assigned to `tempin`.  This causes the next line `tempin[0]` to throw a List Index Out of Bounds error, because there is no 0th element in an empty List.

I suggest making sure that any parameters that you use in your Apex class are set in your test class prior to using them in the Apex class.

Take a look at The [Visualforce Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm), specifically the section on [Testing Custom Controllers and Extensions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm?CSHID=pages_controller_error_handling.htm) for an example and more information.  The example in the Visualforce Developer's Guide is explained more in a section of the [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods developer force page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods#Test_Methods_and_Visualforce_Controllers).

Comment: I didn't know it works just to put ApexPages.currentPage()... ;) Still if he's learning - I'd advise to teach using Test.setCurrentPage() instead ;) http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm

Comment: As a Newbie to Test class Can you please explain somewhat more clearly if possible with an example.